# Can I restart dependent service with systemd?

Tags: debian, systemd

I have created two services, one for a rails app and another for its delayed_job process, I want to restart the delayed_job service everytime the rails service is restarted, can I do this with systemd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Requires=` on the delayed_job systemd file does the job:

```
[Unit]
Requires=rails.service
```

(`man systemd.unit`)

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using `BindsTo` over `Requires`, from `man systemd.unit`

```
BindsTo=
  Configures requirement dependencies, very similar in style to Requires=, however in addition to this behavior, it also
  declares that this unit is stopped when any of the units listed suddenly disappears. Units can suddenly, unexpectedly
  disappear if a service terminates on its own choice, a device is unplugged or a mount point unmounted without
  involvement of systemd.
```